# set Icon on right side of a Item in AlertDialog.setItems

Tags: android

I use AlertDialog method and inside this dialog i make a list with setItems.

It is possible to add an icon in the right side of the item?

My example code:

```
final CharSequence ex[] = {
    Html.fromHtml("Text"),
    Html.fromHtml("Text"),
    Html.fromHtml("Text")
};

AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

dialog.setTitle("Title");
dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
dialog.setItems(ex, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int w){
         // do something...
    }
});

// OR

dialog.setSingleChoiceItems(ex, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int w){
         // do something...
    }
});

dialog.create();
dialog.show();
```

Or in simple way, use a SingleChoiceItems and change radio icon for my personal icon.

Thanks.

Comment: create custom `Dialog` for that

Comment: Can you show me an example using my code?

Comment: You want an AlertDialog filled with list items, and each list item should have an icon right?

Comment: https://github.com/mohit008/Android-Dialog/blob/master/src/com/dialog/MainActivity.java

Comment: Thanks Mohit for the sample but is not exactly what i'm looking for, because i need use list array. And KingBryan yes.